# How to run a function each time a checkbox is checked via jQuery?

Tags: jquery, function, checkbox

I've read a number of questions on here but am still a little confused on the best way to handle checkboxes in jQuery.

For the following HTML:

```
<div><input type="checkbox" id="checkBox"/>Checkbox</div>
```

I would like to run a JavaScript function when the user clicks the checkbox, but not when the user unchecks the checkbox.

I've been trying code using the jQuery `.is(':checked')` but can't seem to get any response, and when I tried to use and if...else statement within `$("#checkBox").change(function() {})` to go back and forth all kinds of wonky things happened.

Any advice on how to start?  Very early beginner here so thanks for your patience.

Comment: Please post the jQuery you tried.

Comment: As lonesomeday pointed out in a buried comment, `checkBox.checked` will return true or false, where `checkBox` is the actual DOM input-checkbox element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#checkBox").change(function() {
    if( this.checked ){
        // yesh here
    }
})
```

Added the native JS after a comment. To expand a little, if you can, use native JS. Almost all normal situations it's faster and less resource-consuming. For that same reason you dont use `$(this).attr('id')` but `this.id`

That has to be placed in a document ready, if yyou prefer the `.on()` method:

```
$("#checkBox").on('change', function() {
    if( this.checked ){
        // yesh here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#checkbox-id').change(function() { // change #checkbox-id with our checkbox id
    var el = $(this);
    if (el.prop('checked')) {
       // add your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by:

```
$('#checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        // Do your stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: Or, to make it a lot quicker, `if (this.checked) {`.